# jQuery.trigger => Selector:toggle on Cloned Element = Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Cloned menu (.original / .cloned ) i have problem getting 1 of the 2 toggle functions to work correctly.

### **Part #1 Cloned Menu Toggle**

```
$('.mobile-nav-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $('a');

    if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
        $this.trigger('mobilenav:close', [$this, 'close']);
    } else {
        $this.trigger('mobilenav:close', [$this, 'open']);
    }
    // Guess this one get executed twice
    $this.trigger('mobilenav:toggle', [$this]);
});
```

### **Part #2 Cloned Menu Toggle**

```
$(document).on('mobilenav:toggle', function(e, $obj) {
    $('.original>div>nav').toggleClass('open').slideToggle(300);
    $('.cloned>div>nav').toggleClass('open').slideToggle(300);
    $obj.toggleClass('close');
});
```

I understand the issue is that am using $('a') as my selector make **mobilenav:toggle** trigger twice and then it will loop around opening and closing the two menus.

On the other hand the mobile-nav-toggle icon don't loop and syncs correctly, menu drawer is in sync but looping.

**If i change**

```
$this = $('a');
// To
$this = $(this);
```

Everything will work except toggle icon that will not be in sync.

Have given this a couple of hours now and my macro level of **Javascript / jQuery** is just to weak as probably can be seen on my half ass solution on **Part #2**.

**Watch my masterpiece in action!**

[image: jQuery toggle loop]

Help me do this as a pro !

**Edit: Adding rest of code from Sticky / cloning function after request**

```
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('margin-top', '0').css('z-index', '100').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);

function stickMenu() {

    var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
    orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {    
        orgElement = $('.original');
        coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
        leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;
        widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
        $('.cloned').css('left', leftOrgElement + 'px').css('top', 0).css('width', widthOrgElement).show();
        $('.original').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.original>div>nav').removeAttr("id", "off-nav");
    } else {
        $('.cloned').hide();
        $('.original>div>nav').attr("id", "off-nav");
        $('.original').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
}
```

**Edit: Added Markup**

```
<header class="menu" id="main-header-wrap"">
    <div class="" id="main-header">
        <div class="toptop"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="logotype">         
                </div>
                <div id="menu-container" class="clearfix">
                    <a class="mobile-nav-toggle lines-button x skiplink">
                        <span class="lines"></span>
                    </a>
                    <nav>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="off-nav">
            <ul><li class=""></li></ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Could you post rest of your code ?

Comment: @DinoMyte  Added code used to clone and stick menu.

Comment: also need the markup

Comment: @DinoMyte added the markup that should be of any interest